# SQL Server Generate Script fails after Determining objects in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio. I use the Task -> Generate Script to generate scripts for the whole database. I've used this process successfully before, however now I'm getting an error.

There error report says The Table '[schema].[table]' does not exist on the server. The schema it's reporting is not a schema I use anywhere, at least not on purpose, but it is a User. The table is a real table, in a different schema.

I've looked at the most recently changed tables and views and I can't find any reference to the schema in the error report. Any idea what's going on or how I can find the source of the error?

Update: I ran an experiment and didn't check the "Script all objects in selected database" option. This means I also couldn't use the "Database Create" option. However, everything else the same, and selecting all objects available, it successfully created all scripts.

Comment: That's...odd.  Only thing I can think of is that user created a table and you don't have rights to see the table in the SSMS tree, or read the table schema (which would cause script generation to blow up).  Can you connect as sa?

Comment: I got signed in as sa. sys.schemas lists the schema shown in the error message, but sys.objects lists no objects with that schema_id. I tried to run the task while logged in as sa and got the same error message.